# How to plot a Bar plot in ggplot2 using R-language

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set like this:

```
data        which   repticker
40.87000    actual      603126
38.36000    actual      603168
15.04000    actual      603188
14.07000    actual      603306
7.42000     actual      603328
58.84818    model.pred  603126
41.74658    model.pred  603168
40.30288    model.pred  603188
28.19353    model.pred  603306
60.13398    model.pred  603328
```

I want to plot the result like this:

[image]

My code is here, but it only plot 3 stocks.

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x=repticker, y=data, fill=which)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.5, position="dodge", colour="black") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel1")
```

Comment: @TylerRinker,sorry, I just changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because `repticker` is numeric and you want it treated as a factor.  So wrap it with `as.factor` as follows:

```
dd <- read.table(text="data        which   repticker
40.87000    actual      603126
38.36000    actual      603168
15.04000    actual      603188
14.07000    actual      603306
7.42000     actual      603328
58.84818    model.pred  603126
41.74658    model.pred  603168
40.30288    model.pred  603188
28.19353    model.pred  603306
60.13398    model.pred  603328", header=TRUE)

ggplot(dd, aes(x=as.factor(repticker), y=data, fill=which)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=0.5, position="dodge", colour="black") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Pastel1")
```

[image]

From my perspective this is easier to view/compare (as I assume this is your purpose) as a line geom as follows:

```
ggplot(dd, aes(x=as.factor(repticker), y=data, color=which, group=which)) + 
  geom_line(size=1)
```

[image]

A dotplot may be useful as well.

Comment: You probably need to take `width` out to completely match his desired output

Comment: @DavidArenburg Agreed but it was part of the OP's original code and I assumed they wanted it in there.